# Install failed when installing PDO sqlsrv on debian 12 with PHP 8.3

Tags: debian, software-installation, sqlserver

I want to install `pdo_sqlsrv` on a Debian 12 server with PHP 8.3. I'm following the documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-on-debian).

The latest version seems to be perfect ([5.12.0](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.12.0)), but I can't install it. After doing this as the doc said:

```bash
apt-get install curl apt-transport-https
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y php8.3 php8.3-dev php8.3-xml php8.3-intl unixodbc-dev unixodbc odbcinst
```

I'm doing this:

```bash
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

And I always have this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/sqlsrv"
install failed
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pdo_sqlsrv"
install failed
```

I also tried [this tuto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=debian18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline) from microsoft, but I got "Package `msodbcsql17` not found"

I don't know how to install it. How can I fix it ?